# How to Restore Windows 10 From C: Drive Clone?

Tags: windows-10, partition-recovery, disk-cloning

I did a mistake while cloning my existing Windows 10 sytem. I could clone only C:\ drive of my PC. Where as There were three partitions on SSD

- Recovery
- MBR Boot Record
- C:\Drive

Is it possible to restore my machine with just C:\ drive?

Comment: Please don't shout in your title...

Comment: At the very least, you need the MBR partition and the system partition, in order to boot Windows while using only SSD. My suggestion is just clone the drive the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you have valid backup you can restore system but you need to manually(from windows installation stick/disk) install boot loader to work your system.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to install Windows 10 manually, then restore your C: partition on top of the new Windows 10 C: partition leaving the others alone.

If you still have access to the original drive it may be faster to simply clone it again taking all the required data at once.